# Teradata SQL - What does TableStatsV show?

Tags: teradata

What does the TableStatsV show ?
I thought it shows the statistics of every table..
but when I execute

```
Select * FROM TablesV
```

I get way more results then I get with executing:

```
Select * FROM TableStatsV
```

So why is it like that ? Why does TableStatsV contains not all tables ?

Comment: It shows tables where statistics were collected. If some tables are missing there's no stats collected on them

Comment: Also note that despite the name TablesV lists many objects that are not Tables - Views, Macros, Stored Procedures, Functions, etc. Check the documentation on TableKind column.